# Push Notification on android device from Application.through .net web service

Tags: android, push-notification, push

Push Notification on android device from Application,through .net web service,i need to show notification in android device even i was sign out my id and close my application also,

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud Messaging for Android (GCM) is a service that allows you to send data from your server to your users' Android-powered device. 
for more details follow this link http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html